# Vlookup VBA Code in Excel, not copying data in the right cell (Need just a small fix in my code)

Tags: vba, excel

I need a little help with fixing the VBA code that I have written.
Question:

I have an excel file with 3 columns on sheet1 ("Name", "ID" and "Name Data"): "Name Data" is a blank column.

```
Name        ID      Name Data
Albert      4235 
John        4237 
Robert      4239 
Micky       4241 
Minnie      4243 
Donalid     4245 
Edited      4247 
Goofy       4249
```

On sheet 2, there is a similar ID column with only one ID: eg:

```
ID
4243
```

I have the vlookup code to match the ID value on sheet2 (in this eg, that would be "4243") with ID value on sheet 1 and copy the name associated with that ID to "Name data" of sheet1. The final result should look like this:

```
Name       ID    Name Data
Albert    4235 
John      4237 
Robert    4239 
Micky     4241 
Minnie    4243     Minnie
Donalid   4245 
Edited    4247 
Goofy     4249
```

Issue: The issue with this code is that it copies the name onto first cell under "Name data". Eg: it does the following:

```
Name      ID      Name Data
Albert    4235     Minnie
John      4237 
Robert    4239 
Micky     4241 
Minnie    4243 
Donalid   4245 
Edited    4247 
Goofy     4249
```

The name "minnie" should get copied on 5th row under "Name data" and not on 1st row (excluding heading rows)

Can anyone please suggest me what to fix in the code?

Thanks a ton!

Here is the code:

```
Sub lookup()
x = 2
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b4:b8")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A2")
For Each c1 In rng1
For Each c2 In rng2
If c1.Value = c2.Value Then
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value = c2.Value
If c1.Value <> c2.Value Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value
x = x + 1
End If
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

I know that it has something to do with this line:

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value = c2.Value
```

but I am not able to figure out what.

Comment: Could you please share your actual file? I see many contradictions in code and sheets naming. Moreover, look carefully at `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 3).Value` - what's the purpose to assign the cell value to itself?

Comment: Why are you using VBA for this? You should be able to achieve this easily with an INDEX / MATCH construct

Comment: @PeterL. Thanks. I am not sure how to attach the file here. Can you tell me please. I am very new to stackoverflow. I serached the forum and it says you cannot attach a file here.

Comment: @JustinJDavies Thanks. I have to do this with a large set of data, so VBA is more quick and easy, I beleive.

Comment: @datacentric upload it to dropbox or any similar filesharing, and drop the link here.

Comment: @PeterL. I know what you meant about contradictions with sheet names. I fixed the sheet names in the code. I hope it is making sense now. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @PeterL. Here is the link to file: http://www.ge.tt/#!/6PjEaRX/v/0       Thanks for youe help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished up with the following code:

```
Sub lookup()

Set rng1 = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B2:B19")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A2:A2")

For Each c1 In rng1
    For Each c2 In rng2
        If c2.Value = c1.Value Then
            Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(c1.Row, 3).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(c1.Row, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Your corrected file is shared: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nsr1iuwnzt1s1x/VlookupVBA.xlsm

Comment: @datacentric you're welcome buddy - I'm just a learner as you are, 4 months ago I had no clue about VBA at all)

Comment: @datacentric I'd also suggest you do not neglect the above comment to use functions - the job is enough simple to do that without VBA code, unless it is a part of another big project.

Comment: Absolutely! It just that, I have do this for more than 200 excel files, so I thought VBA is a better idea.

Comment: @datacentric oh i see) in case you need some help with files looping - do not hesitate to start a new thread.